# Flex 3.0 : Showing data in the legend of a Pie Chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts, customization, legend, pie-chart

I'm a newbie to Adobe Flex 3.0. I need to show data within the Pie Chart Legend, alongside the colored markers. I have a few vague ideas about how to go about it. (Maybe I would have to write my custom legendMarkerRenderer.) Could anybody give any pointers? There aren't many examples on the net regarding this.

Thanks in advance!

P.R.

Comment: It would be a good idea to specify that this is a question regarding Flex in the title or at least in the question description. The flex tag is the only pointer to that and I am pretty sure it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the data on the Legend you will need to extend LegendItem class. Example you can see in my blog: <s>http://northam.blogspot.com/2009/05/flex-showing-data-in-legend-of-pie.html</s>

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really useful link for you. The Flex 3 Component explorer... It has examples of how to implement the majority, if not all, of the adobe flex components.  If you want something more complex you may need to extend legend and create you own component. By the sounds of things it should give you enough to go on

<s>[Flex 3 Component Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/componentexplorer/explorer.html)</s> (broken link)

Answer (score 1):

You can always customize the UI controls in flex as per ur requirements. 
So you can extend the legend class

have a look @ this also:[liveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=charts_formatting_110_42.html)